# Laravel 4 : Route doesn't match with trailing slash, how to make?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, routes

this route doesn't match :

```
 Route::get('/{cat}/',
    array('as' => 'article_cat', 'uses' => 'ArticleController@cat'))
    ->where('cat', $pattern_str);
```

Without trailing slash the route match.
It's not Apache the cause of error, I tested with the trailing slash URL and replacing the contents of public/index.php. It's ok domain.com/the-cat/ display index.php content.
But not work with Laravel4.

I found a lot of messages and issues with this problem but no solution.
My client use this type of URL and do not want to change the URLs in the new version (normal) of its site.

An idea please ?

Answer (score 0):

The Silex Micro-Framework does a better job with this - it forces the one that you want (for SEF-purposes).

Your best bet, for Laravel, would be to declare your routes **without** the trailing slash, and force Apache to add the slash on any incoming URL.

So, a route definition would look like this:

```
Route::get('my/page' ...);
```

Your HyperText Access (.htaccess) `RewriteRule` would look like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2/[L,R=301 ]
```

That code block should come before any others - it should even be the first rule that gets executed.

So, when you visit `my/page`, you'll be redirected to `my/page/`, but the `GET my/page` route will be loaded.

(Note: this works with my projects - I don't know if Laravel's code base has been altered.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but Apache is not the solution because it is Laravel forcing this behavior.

Comment: If Apache redirects with trailing slash, Laravel will redirect without trailing stash ... infinite redirection. Too much strange behavior of this type in Laravel. Next project I will test Sylex, but for this project I have to finish with Laravel.

Comment: I see - Laravel did not do this before. Silex does this: if you declare a route with a trailing slash, it will always force the slash. Whereas, Laravel would ignore it. If you loaded the route with the slash, then Laravel would load it anyway. That's my experience.